# Import text file with ISO 8601 date/time values (2014-07-02T16:09:49-07:00)

Tags: date, ms-access, import, ms-access-2007, iso8601

When importing a text file into Access 2007 with date/time values like

```
2014-07-02T16:09:49-07:00
```

Access is unable to convert to date and shows the same as text. How do I convert the same in to date/time in Access?

Answer (score 2):

You will probably need to import the ISO 8601 date/time values into a `Text` field, then use an Update query to convert those string values and write them to a `Date/Time` field. The question

[Parsing an ISO8601 date/time (including TimeZone) in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4896116/2144390)

has several answers that include VBA functions you might be able to adapt depending on your specific requirements (and possibly some slight differences in date handling between Excel and Access).