# Convert time on a pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a pivot table with one column that has data like this:

```
14/04/2016 09:15
14/04/2016 10:15
14/04/2016 14:41
14/04/2016 15:46
14/04/2016 15:51
14/04/2016 15:54
14/04/2016 15:59
14/04/2016 15:59
14/04/2016 16:04
14/04/2016 16:06
14/04/2016 16:27
14/04/2016 16:33
14/04/2016 16:38
14/04/2016 16:46
14/04/2016 16:52
```

The problem is the time is currently GMT, and I want to change this to GMT+1.
Can you help me?

Comment: So this column you have in pivot table data source. And now you want to display the data with one hour added to the dates pivot table pivot table data source?

Comment: I am using an SQL Server DB as DataSource, and I just want to convert this to GMT +1 on pivot table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your comment. Convert it directly on SQL Server data source by:

```
select dateadd(HOUR, @num_hours, getdate()) as time_added, 
       getdate() as curr_date
```

In @num_hours input 1

Comment: This was the last way I tried, but it worked nicely. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can parset(function parseDateTime for example) hour for each row,when you read the table do this change and it is to format to the time zone.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I cannot find that function on excel.

Comment: Hi ,you can read this,could be help for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896116/parsing-an-iso8601-date-time-including-timezone-in-excel