# Checking that cell value is date time (ISO)

Tags: vba, excel

Want to check if the cell is a date time value using the ISO format i.e. 
2012-04-12T00:00:00

Current try:

```
If mainsht.Cells(r, 6).Value = "" Or mainsht.Cells(r, 6).Value = "####-##-##T##:##:## Then
GoTo next6
```

Still it does not seem to match the format in vba and cell value, as I have many cells with this correct format and still activating the else statement i.e. not recognized by the `"####-##-##T##:##:##"`.

Maybe yyyy-mm-ddThh-MM-ss?

Comment: When using wild cards you should use `Like`, not `=`

Comment: Are you trying to tell whether there is a string in the cell which looks like a date, or are you trying to tell whether there is a number in the cell which has been formatted in that particular format?  E.g. the current date/time (for me) is the number 42569.628827662 which can be formatted in many different ways, but is still a date.  (And is still a number too.)

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks, this is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: @YowE3K ISO Formatted date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISO date come in several formats, adding an asterisk `"####-##-##T##:##:##*"` would be more versatile.

```
2011-01-01T12:00:00Z
2011-01-01T12:00:00+05:00
2011-01-01T12:00:00-05:00
2011-01-01T12:00:00.05381+05:00
```

Example:

```
If mainsht.Cells(r, 6).Value = "" Or mainsht.Cells(r, 6).Value Like "####-##-##T##:##:##*" Then
```

You might want to look at this post: [Parsing an ISO8601 date/time (including TimeZone) in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896116/parsing-an-iso8601-date-time-including-timezone-in-excel)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Glad that I could help.  Thanks for the check!

Answer (score 0):

The following UDF¹ can be used as a worksheet function or a helper function in a VBA project.

```
Option Explicit

Function IsISODateTime(str As String)
    Dim n As Long, nums() As Variant
    Static rgx As Object, cmat As Object

    'with rgx as static, it only has to be created once; beneficial with repeated calls to the UDF
    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    End If
    IsISODateTime = vbNullString

    With rgx
        .Global = False
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}"
        IsISODateTime = .Test(str)
    End With
End Function
```

The UDF returns a true boolean True/False.

The pattern I've provided is very brick-by-brick literal; it could be shortened using the methods detailed in [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops/22542835#22542835).

---

¹ <sub>A User Defined Function (aka UDF) is placed into a standard module code sheet. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and when the VBE opens, immediately use the pull-down menus to **Insert ► Module** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>). Paste the function code into the new module code sheet titled something like *Book1 - Module1 (Code)*. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet(s).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by Tim Williams do it like so

```
If mainsht.Cells(r, 6).Value = "" Or mainsht.Cells(r, 6).Value Like "####-##-##T##:##:##" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To test the cell for an ISO formatted date you should check the cells NumberFormat property, so your If statement should be:

```
If mainsht.Cells(r, 6).Value = "" Or mainsht.Cells(r, 6).NumberFormat Like "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss*" Then
```

Note: If the currently accepted solution is working, your cell only contains a string value (which **looks** like an ISO formatted date) rather than an actual date displayed using an ISO date format.