# Convert from UTC in Access

Tags: excel, date, ms-access, time, utc

UPDATED - Excel has been answered looking for Access solution now.

I have looked over previous articles but can't find one which quite answers this.

I have a UTC time format - 2016-10-01T18:07:55.410Z

The raw data will be being formatted in excel and placed into an Access database. I don't mind formatting it in excel first then putting it into Access formatted. If it's easier to format in Access then happy for this answer too. I assume excel will be easiest.

The format I would like to see is 01/10/2016 18:07:55

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896116/parsing-an-iso8601-date-time-including-timezone-in-excel

Comment: Yep that's sorted it for excel thank you very much. I would still be interested in an answer for access if anyone has one?

Comment: Access **stores** datetime values the same way as Excel: "... as floating point numbers, counts of days and fractions of a day (times) since midnight, December 30, 1899. The format merely controls how the value is displayed, not what's stored." I guess what you actually what is to apply **display format** for your datetime fields in Access?

Comment: I guess so just anything to correct the date basically so when it's pulled back out of access it's nicely formatted.

Comment: Specify this format string in properties of your Access display controls: `yyyy-mm-ddThh:MM:ss.000Z`.