# How to permanently store custom function in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a custom VBA function in Excel called `Combine`. It simply combine multiple cells in a comma separated sting.

I am able to add the new function by doing the following

1. I clicked ALT + F11
2. Then I clicked on "Insert" then "Module"
3. I inserted the following VBA code into it

.

```
Function Combine(WorkRng As Range, Optional Sign As String = ",") As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim OutStr As String
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    If Rng.Text <> Sign Then
        OutStr = OutStr & "'" & Rng.Text & "'" & Sign
    End If
Next
Combine = Left(OutStr, Len(OutStr) - 1)
End Function
```

Then I can easily execute this function like so `Combine(A1:A25)` to combine all cells A1 to A25 by wrapping them with a single quota and separating the values by a comma.

Then problem is that when I close down excel and open up a new worksheet the function goes away and I can't reuse it.

How can I permanently save this function so I am able to reuse it when new sheet is created?

Comment: [create an add-in](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-add-in-create.htm)

Answer (score 2):

After you write your function in an Excel file, save the file as an .xlam file.  This is an Excel addin file.

Then you need to go to options and addins and load your file.

Now going forward this 'file' will always be open.

You can hit alt-f11 to access it anytime.

[link with details](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-add-in-create.htm) from the famous ozgrid

Comment: so put the code in a a text file and then change the extension? Where would I store this file at?

Comment: @Jaylen no, you save your macro-enabled workbook as an *Excel Add-In* file, and have Excel load that add-in at startup. If you do it right then Excel deals with the "where do I save that" part.

Comment: @Jaylen here is another source.  Scroll down a bit and it will give you step by step instructions with pictures. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-Custom-Functions-in-Excel-2007-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f

Answer (score 0):

I have used this trick to use custom function (mfdate) in workbook added from VBA:

```
Workbooks.Add
sheetArr = Range("AM2:AM10").Value
For i = 1 To UBound(sheetArr, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(sheetArr, 2)
        If Len(CStr(sheetArr(i, j))) Then sheetArr(i, j) = MfDate(CStr(sheetArr(i, j)))
    Next j
Next i
Range("AM2:AM10").Value = sheetArr
```

Answer (score 0):

write function in Module and when u click save, a dialogue Box will appear, in file Type Locate Excel Add in , this will be registered in excel

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35438012)