# Convert DateString with offset to a valid Date/Timestamp in Excel

Tags: excel, date, datetime, excel-formula

I am trying to convert a date string field to a date. Problem is the string field has offset for Eastern time in it. Please suggest how to convert it to date time.

Date String:  **2016-09-21T10:01:43-04:00**

This has to be converted to valid Date Time in Excel.

Comment: You could try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896116/parsing-an-iso8601-date-time-including-timezone-in-excel

Comment: Might be worth asking from where the data is from? Usually the import/export wizards offer options for data conversions and date is often included so you don't have to figure how to convert them.

Answer (score 1):

The sure fire way is to strip each of the elements you need from the string then place them in the appropriate spots in the `DATE` and `TIME` functions.  There are shorter methods which use `DATEVALUE` and `TIMEVALUE`.

Grab the year

```
=LEFT(A1,4)
```

Grab the month

```
=MID(A1,6,2)
```

Grab the day

```
=MID(A1,9,2)
```

Grab the hour

```
=MID(A1,12,2)
```

Grab the minutes

```
=MID(A1,15,2)
```

Grab the seconds

```
=MID(A1,18,2)
```

Time adjustment hour

```
=MID(A1,21,2)
```

Time adjustment minutes

```
=RIGHT(A1,2)
```

Time adjustment direction

```
=MID(A1,20,1)
```

Now that you have stripped out all the elements which are all still strings, you can dump them into DATE(year,month,day) and TIME(Hour, Minutes, Seconds)

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,6,2),MID(A1,9,2))+TIME(MID(A1,12,2),MID(A1,15,2),MID(A1,18,2))+TIME(MID(A1,21,2),RIGHT(A1,2),0)*if(MID(A1,20,1)="-",-1,1)
```

[image: POC]

NOTE:  This answer assumes a leading 0 for single digits days