# excel vba: how to convert ISO 8601 date type to normal date type

Tags: excel, vba, date, date-conversion

I have dates of ISO 8601 type in VBA like:

```
2021-01-19T08:28:31+09:00
```

how can I convert to normal date type in VBA.

I found solution for other program languages but I couldn't find them for VBA.

I also found solution for convertion on excel sheet. But I would like to know how to get it done in macro in Excel.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896116/parsing-an-iso8601-date-time-including-timezone-in-excel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing an ISO8601 date/time (including TimeZone) in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896116/parsing-an-iso8601-date-time-including-timezone-in-excel)

Comment: It depends on, how you wish the time zone offset handled. Ignore? Convert the date/time value to remote time? Convert the date/time value to local time?